# Led light strip flashing

Tags: lighting

I've had my led tape lighting under cabinet lighting for 3 years & it has just in the past week begun to flash on & off when it's turned on. It stops flashing after a few minutes. What could be the problem? I've already checked the strips & connectors & they all work fine. I'm thinking it might be in the connection of the on/off switch. It is plugged into an outlet inside my cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a connection issue, those don't get better over time. your driver is failing because the capacitors in it are drying out. this will get worse sooner than later.

As the LED strip warms, it uses more current. To supply more current, the driver increases its output voltage. When the voltage increases, a cap of a given capacity stores more energy. When the voltage catches up with demand, the flickering stops. Note that higher voltages tend to heat the capacitors and cause them to age even faster; a run-away cycle you're in the early stages of.

Answer (score 0):

LED strips are powered by an electronic driver that controls current and voltage. These driver devices fail like they do in other AC LED lights.